# How can I add another argument to CompareTo method?

Tags: c#

How can I add another argument to the CompareTo method so I can implement a switch statement to allow my program to select what the CompareTo method will be comparing?

Current I'm doing:

```
public int CompareTo(Employee other)
        {
            return name.CompareTo(other.name);
        }
```

What I want to do:

```
public int CompareTo(Employee other, string choice)
        {
            switch(choice)
            {
                 case "name":
                     return name.CompareTo(other.name);
                 case "number"
                     return number.CompareTo(other.number);
            }
            return name.CompareTo(other.name);
        }
```

Comment: Have you not just provided the answer as part of your question?

Comment: Is this question regarding _String_.CompareTo() ?

Comment: Take a look at IComparable<>.  _"The role of IComparable is to provide a method of comparing two objects of a particular type."_

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're asking how you can extend the functionality of existing classes that you can't modify (otherwise you could directly edit the class itself), and if that's the case, I'd recommend making an extension method as such:

```
public static class EmployeeExtensions {
    public static int CompareTo(this Employee baseEmployee, Employee other, string choice){
         ... code ....
         return 0;
    }
}
```

This will then allow you to extend the compare to functionality, and call this from wherever you require it. You need to put the extension method in its own static class.

You can call it by going:

```
Employee a = new Employee(...);
Employee b = new Employee(...);
a.CompareTo(b, "args");
```

Assuming the extension class has been imported where you are trying to use it. This is usually the way C# allows for extending functionality of classes you do not have access to. Although if you do have access to the class I'd recommend editing the class itself and making a new method (you may be able to override, but if they provide distinct functionality you'll need to write two methods, in this case code duplication is ok).

This doesn't apply if you're actually trying to change the default equality members, and if that's the case, you can't add your own argument and have it still work with existing infrastructure such as list sorting, so I'd recommend re-evaluating your problem if you 'want to add an argument to equals' for example.

If you're trying to change the way objects compare (objects implementing IComparable), then make your own IComparer, and use that to do the comparing, don't try and change the way CompareTo is done on the class, as the default behavior of Compare (with arguments as is) is useful. I'm also not saying don't implement IComparable (rather than making a IComparer) if it makes sense and you have access to the class then use an IComparable, but that won't allow you to change the arguments of the inherited compare method.

Comment: The net effect is no different to the OP's original

Comment: @MickyD I'd agree in the general case, but in the case OP doesn't have access to original class it is different, and in the case OP has access but is trying to make use of a 'comparer' I've also addressed that with a comparator, but I'm just trying to suggest a few ways for him to achieve things in different circumstances. Because it seems from his question directly modifying the original class isn't a solution. (*he/she for whole comment)

Comment: Where does OP state they don't have access to original class?   Anyway, the way this sort of thing is normally done is by wring a new comparison static object that implements IComparable<>. _"The role of IComparable is to provide a method of comparing two objects of a particular type."_

Comment: By nature of the his question referring to code that would achieve what he is asking if he had access to the initial class, I state the assumption that he doesn't have access. Then at the end I talk about comparators and comparables as you suggest. I've covered a few different bases due to the original ambiguous nature of the question, but happy to add more.

Comment: Incorrect.  His very **first** code snippet clearly says _"Current[ly] **I'm** doing:"_

Comment: `I assume you're asking`, `This doesn't apply if you're actually trying to`, `If you're trying to change the way objects compare `. I feel I covered all three interpretations in order of how likely I think they are, but in any case, I don't feel like I've neglected any information?

Comment: What _may be_ is not as important as the facts.  Besides, your use of extension methods is an example of not how to do things.  As I said, it is no different to what OP is doing.